# Is conduction a mechanical wave?

Tags: thermodynamics

A wave is defined as a disturbance which carries energy from one point to another point.

In a mechanical wave, energy is carried by the wave from one point to another point by the vibration of particles. But the particles of the medium do not themselves travel along with the wave.

Radiation is a form of electromagnetic waves ( infrared waves ).

In conduction, heat energy is transferred from one point to another point by the vibration of particles ( atoms and free electrons ) that make up an object.
But the particles themselves do not move.

Conduction and Mechanical Waves have a similar definition.

So is conduction of heat a type of mechanical wave ?

PS: I am a junior high school student so please explain the answer in simple terms.

Comment: Transient conduction travels as kind of a diffusive wave (with no sharp wave fronts).

Answer (score 1):

> A wave is defined as a disturbance which carries energy from one point to another point.

Not a good definition, for physics definition:

> [wave,](https://www.britannica.com/science/wave-physics) propagation of disturbances from place to place in *a regular and organized way*. Most familiar are surface waves that travel on water, but sound, light,

note the italics I put.

> Radiation is a form of electromagnetic waves ( infrared waves ).

There are many ways the word is used in physics, it is also used for [particle radioactivity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay)

> In conduction, heat energy is transferred from one point to another point by the vibration of particles ( atoms and free electrons ) that make up an object. But the particles themselves do not move.

But there is not the *regular and organized way of waves*, it is a continuum. In addition the atoms taking part in heat transfer do move, with vibrations at the microscopic level.

> Conduction and Mechanical Waves have a similar definition.

No . If you study further in physics you will find that waves obey ["wave equations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation), which can describe their actions and predict new situations. Conductivity does not. It is true that once one has complete mathematical solutions of a differential equations those solutions, often, can be used collectively, by summing mathematical series of them  to describe non regular processes, for example one can model with wave equations solutions a [peak of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) going down a stream, but this also does not model conductivity.